# Need help in Smarty output in WHMCS clientarea

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I want get domain statues in WHMCS client area by using below code, but its output showing duplicate values, is there any help so i can remove duplicate values.

```
{foreach key=num item=status from=$domains}
<li><a href="#"><span>{$status.statustext}</span></a></li>{/foreach}
```

Output is something below, but i don't want duplicate values like Pending 2 time or more if more domains are pending.

Pending

Pending

Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend extracting the statustext for each domain using [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). This would give you a new array from which you can easily remove any duplicate values using [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) or [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). Here are a few ways to accomplish this:

**Combine array_column() with array_unique() to remove duplicates.** This is probably the most common sense approach which could help with readability in the future. The $domains array is sent to array_column() which extracts the statustext values. The result is then sent to array_unique to remove any duplicate values.

```
{foreach item=statustext from=$domains|@array_column:'statustext'|@array_unique}
<li><a href="#"><span>{$statustext}</span></a></li>{/foreach}
```

**Use array_column() only and set 'statustext' as the array index.** This method uses one less function call, perhaps making it slightly more efficient  at the cost of some readability. A second parameter can be specified in array_column() to extract another column as the index for the newly created array. Duplicate array indexes are merged/overwritten so setting an index to match it's values will prevent duplicates from being stored.

```
{foreach item=statustext from=$domains|@array_column:'statustext':'statustext'}
<li><a href="#"><span>{$statustext}</span></a></li>{/foreach}
```

**Combine array_column() with array_count_values() to remove duplicates.** It might be useful to have the count of each status since you are aggregating data from multiple domains. Applying array_count_values() to the results of array_column() will remove duplicate values while also giving you the count of each value.

```
{foreach key=statustext item=count from=$domains|@array_column:'statustext'|@array_count_values}
<li><a href="#"><span>{$statustext}: {$count}</span></a></li>{/foreach}
```